# UICollectionView - Disallow focus on entire collectionView, only on cells

Tags: uicollectionview, focus, tvos

I have a UICollectionView and a UIButton above the collection view. My preferredFocus for the controller is the collection view, and this works fine on viewWillAppear, focusing on the first cell.

However, when I focus on the button and then return focus down to the collectionView, sometimes the entire collectionView becomes focused, and it's hard to get focus on one of the cells. Sometimes it focuses back from button to a cell, like it should.

I do have:
`containerCollectionView?.remembersLastFocusedIndexPath = true` already

How to prevent the entire collectionView from receiving focus?

Comment: If you have already set remembersLastFocusedIndexPath=true, you might solve this with also implementing
UICollectionViewDelegate's
indexPathForPreferredFocusedViewInCollectionView(_:)

Comment: @phikin I just came back to this and found that - works great.